# Ruby module methods accessibility

Tags: ruby, methods, module, scope

I have the following module:

```
module Foo
  def f1 x
   puts "f1(#{x})"
  end
  def Foo.f2 x
   puts "f2(#{x})"
  end
end
```

When it is included into a class:

```
class Bar
    include Foo

    Foo.f2 "bar"   # This works
    f1 "bar"       # Missing method

    def b x
        f1 x       # This works too
    end
end
```

Why is the behavior of f1 different in the two cases?

How is the scope of module metods defined?

Can f1 be written in such a way, that it would work as in the case `f1 "bar"`? Like for example the `task` in Rakefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add class methods to `Bar` you'd want to use `included`; see [Yehuda's post on the subject](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/). It depends (somewhat) on what you're actually trying to do.